# An extra keyboard in my system

Tags: windows-7, drivers, device-manager

I've got 2 devices labeled "HID Keyboard Device" in my system, though I have only one keyboard. How can I figure out what the second device is?

Comment: What kind of system is it (desktop, laptop, what model, etc.)? Do you have any kind of USB device that can insert text, such as a Yubikey?

Comment: @CBHacking, custom desktop. No such devices. Only a mouse, webcam, speakers, Wi-Fi dongle.